# R - read.table imports half of the dataset - no errors nor warnings

Tags: r, import-from-csv

I have a csv file with ~200 columns and ~170K rows.  The data has been extensively groomed and I know that it is well-formed.  When read.table completes, I see that approximately half of the rows have been imported.  There are no warnings nor errors.  I set options( warn = 2 ).  I'm using 64-bit latest version and I increased the memory limit to 10gig.  Scratching my head here...no idea how to proceed debugging this.

**Edit**
When I said half the file, I don't mean the first half.  The last observation read is towards the end of the file....so its seemingly random.

Comment: Is it just getting the first half of the file, or seemingly lines at random? You don't say, and its important.

Comment: @Spacedman - great question!  Seemingly random now that I checked.  The last observation in memory is towards the bottom of the file.

Comment: Looks like you've got your answer now. First thing I might have done is taken the first few lines to see which ones would be read or not. Always worth getting something working on a small dataset before a huge one!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may have a comment character (#) in the file (try setting the option `comment.char = ""` in read.table).  Also, check that the quote option is set correctly.

Comment: I had had comment.char = "", but as soon as I set quote="" I was able to read all observations!

Comment: That did it for me. Weird & worrying! Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem before how I approached it was to read in a set number of lines at a time and then combine after the fact.

```
df1 <- read.csv(..., nrows=85000) 
df2 <- read.csv(..., skip=84999, nrows=85000) 
colnames(df1) <- colnames(df2)

df <- rbind(df1,df2) 
rm(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when reading in a large txt file which had a "|" separator.  Scattered about the txt file were some text blocks that contained a quote (") which caused the read.xxx function to stop at the prior record without throwing an error.  Note that the text blocks mentioned were not encased in double quotes; rather, they just contained one double quote character here and there (") which tripped it up.

I did a global search and replace on the txt file, replacing the double quote (") with a single quote ('), solving the problem (all rows were then read in without aborting).