# read.table creates too few rows, but readLines has the right number

Tags: r

I am trying to import a tab separated list into R.

It is 81704 rows long. However, read.table is only creating 31376. Here is my code:

```
population <- read.table('population.txt', header=TRUE,sep='\t',na.strings = 'NA',blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
```

There are no # commenting anything out.

Here are the first few lines:

```
[1] "NAME\tSTATENAME\tPOP_2009"      "Alabama\tAlabama\t4708708"      "Abbeville city\tAlabama\t2934"  "Adamsville city\tAlabama\t4782"
[5] "Addison town\tAlabama\t711"
```

When I read it raw, readLines gives the right number.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: A couple of ideas: are there any quotes " or ' in the file?  If so, it may be parsing a newline into one of the fields.  Another possibility: are there any mixed CR (\r) and LF (\n) characters?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/5684525/168747

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check with `count.fields` what's in file:

```
n <- count.fields('population.txt', sep='\t', blank.lines.skip=FALSE)
```

Then you could check

```
length(n) # should be 81705 (it count header so rows+1), if yes then:
table(n) # show you what's wrong
```

Then you `readLines` your file and check rows with wrong number of fields. (e.g.  `x<-readLines('population.txt'); head(x[n!=6])`)

Comment: Good answer, I forgot count.fields(). It takes all the same arguments as read.table(), so makes for a good check.

Comment: @neilfws Yes. But I think that your suggestions about `quote=""` is what he need.

Answer (score 17):

Difficult to diagnose without seeing the input file, but the usual suspects are quotes and comment characters (even if you think there are none of the latter).  You can try:

```
quote = "", comment.char = ""
```

as arguments to read.table() and see if that helps.

Comment: I was having the similar problem with readline() returning almost double as much as read.table(). your suggestion worked like a charm. thanks.. though I still have around 200 lines not being reported by R. .. now i am using `read.table(... header=TRUE, sep="|", na.strings = "NA", fill=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote = "", comment.char = "")`

Comment: Has anyone considered making this behavior the default?